# How can I query for list of packageIds for Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_Snapshot and their corresponding size ranges?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Currently I check if snapshot space has not been provisioned to my Endurance block storage, and then try and request snapshot space.

```
    iscsi_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, iscsi_identifier[0],'iSCSI')
    storage = SL.instance(sl_config).storage.getObject(mask=obj_mask, id=iscsi_id)

    if 'snapshotCapacityGb' not in storage:
        print "Error: there is no snapshot space allocated for Volume ID:  {0}".format(iscsi_id)
        order = {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade",
            "packageId": 240,
            "prices": [{

                "id": 144295
            }],

            "volumeId": iscsi_id
        }

        SL.instance(sl_config).storage_order.verifyOrder(order)
```

In return, I get

```
faultCode=SoftLayer_Exception_Public, faultString=The price for 10 GB Storage Space (#144295) is not valid for location
```

Where/how can I get a mapping of snapshot space "id" to request the proper storage?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get the prices for snapshot spaces, making a single call, the [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) makes some internal calls to get the proper prices.

You can get the **identifiers(ids)** for snapshot spaces like [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) does, using the following script:

```
"""
This script retrieves the prices that could be used to place an order for
snapshot space

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getProperties
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Define your SoftLayer's username and apikey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Define the StorageId, for which you want to get the prices for snapshot space
storageId = 1559988

# Define packageId : 240
packageId = 240

# Create Client connection
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
packageService = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package']
storageService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage']

try:
    # Getting provisioned IOPS from storage
    iopsValue = storageService.getProperties(filter={"properties": {"type": {"keyname": {"operation": "PROVISIONED_IOPS"}}}}, id=storageId)
    # Getting snapshot space
    storageSize = storageService.getObject(mask="mask[serviceResource[networkDevice[datacenter]]]", id=storageId)

    # Getting IOPS e.g: 0.25, 2, 4
    x = int(iopsValue[0]['value']) / int(storageSize['capacityGb'])
    if(x == 0.25):
        x = 100
    elif(x == 2):
        x = 200
    elif(x == 4):
        x = 300

    # Define an object filter to get prices
    objectFilter = {"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_snapshot_space"}},
                                   "locationGroupId": {"operation": "is null"},
                                   "item": {"capacity": {"operation": "<=" + str(storageSize['capacityGb'])}},
                                   "capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": x},
                                   "capacityRestrictionMaximum": {"operation": x},
                                   }}
    # Getting prices
    prices = packageService.getItemPrices(filter=objectFilter, id=packageId)
    for price in prices:
        print("Price: %s Capacity: %s" % (price['id'], price['item']['capacity']))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the prices. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

You can use the identifiers in the call that you did.

---

Just in case, you need to use:

> "complexType":
>   "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace"

instead of:

> "complexType":
>   "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade"

if the storage doesn't have a snapshot yet.
I hope it helps, let me know any doubt or comment